# Save all matplotlib plots separately at the end without changing previous code

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

Is it possible to save all plots separately at the end of code? Something like

```
#pseudocode
for each in xrange(no_of_plot):
   plt.savefig('test'+str(each)+'.png')
```

If the code produces 10 plots, I should get 10 `.png` file with name `test0` to `test9`.

One thing is I don't know `no_of_plot` here but I can run the code once to know the number if it has no better way. The main point is -- is it possible to have a loop for `plt.savefig` at the end without having to change the previous code?

Add: plots are generated by

```
def calc_chrom():
  ...
  fig_01 = plt.figure(figsize=(18,11),tight_layout=True)
  ax_nHchrom = plt.subplot2grid((2, 5), (0, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=4)
  ax_nHchrom.plot(each_nparray01.T) # plot numpy array
  ax_nHchrom2 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 5), (1, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=4)
  ax_nHchrom2.plot(each_nparray02.T)
  ...

def calc_mas():  
  fig_02 = plt.figure(figsize=(17,17),tight_layout=True)
  ...
```

Each plot is imported from different functions in different files.

Comment: How are your plots generated?

Comment: @minterm I added the info in the question.

Comment: If you have figure objects, what's the problem with just calling their `savefig()` methods and not that of `plt`?

Comment: @fjarri Because without loop, `savefig()` saves only one last figure. And my purpose is I don't want to change the previous written functions, I want to add saving all plots loop (or lines) at the end of the code.

Comment: I think fjarri meant to call `fig_xy.savefig()` instead of `plt.savefig()`. But I assume, you don't have access to the `fig_xy`-variables, because they are hidden inside the scope of the plot-functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the list of numbers of open figures:

```
for i in plt.get_fignums():
    plt.figure(i).savefig('/wherever/files/shall/roam/figure' + str(i) + '.png')
```